# Nodejs Error: Error: ENOENT, stat './templates'

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to fix my nodemailer.

One problem that I can see is the following when trying to send a mail:

```
[Error: Error: ENOENT, stat './templates']
```

Here is my email code:

```
    var transportBatch = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'smtp.learningbank.dk',
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 587,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    auth: {
        user: 'support@user.dk',
        pass: 'password'
    }
}));

var Render = function(locals) {
    this.locals = locals;
    this.send = function(err, html, text) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            transportBatch.sendMail({
                from: 'user <support@user.dk>',
                to: locals.username,
                subject: 'Din adgangskode til ****!',
                html: html,
                // generateTextFromHTML: true,
                text: text
            }, function(err, responseStatus) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(responseStatus.message);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    this.batch = function(batch) {
        batch(this.locals, templatesDir, this.send);
    };
};

// Send multiple emails
template('password', true, function(err, batch) {
    for(var user in userArray) {
        var render = new Render(userArray[user]);
        render.batch(batch);
    }
                        });
```

At the top of this file I have the following:

```
    crypto = require('crypto'),
bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
XLSX = require('xlsx'),
async = require('async'),
path = require('path'),
nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport'),
templatesDir = './templates',
emailTemplates = require('email-templates');
```

It does not send an email but seems to skip it.